# Null pointer exception on scren rotate android

Tags: android, exception, null, rotation, screen

enter code hereI have the `android:configChanges="orientation"` in manifest but for some reason after rotating the view its going to next activity and `NullPointerException`

```
12-03 17:28:42.673: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10537): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.is.mbank/com.is.mbank.ui.mobileBanking.TransactionConfirmation}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3740)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1262)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.is.mbank.ui.mobileBanking.TransactionConfirmation.onCreate(TransactionConfirmation.java:45)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
        ... 12 more
```

HERE is the code for TransactionConfirmation

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.transaction_confirmation);

        paymentUtil = new PaymentUtil(this);

        textViewFrom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.from);
        textViewTo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.to);
        textViewAmount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.amount);
        textViewCurrency = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currency);

        from = paymentUtil.paymentData.get(Constants.ACCOUNT_NUMBER_FROM).toString();
```

its generatign a null pointer exception on the last row

Comment: post your code and logcat

Comment: share your code to get help soon...

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android?rq=1

Comment: its an activity not an application , cant change it extend Application.

Comment: TransactionConfirmation.java:45 what is line number 45 in TransactionConfirmation.java class

Comment: @user2877963 when orientation changes activity is destroyed and recreated. Looks like line 4 `TransactionConfirmation.java` is null. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: this could happen if you have another layout file for the new orientation, where views are missing or not all id's are specified

Comment: what is "from " here??

Comment: a String and paymentUtil.paymentData is a static Map<String, Object>

Answer (score 2):

change according below in your manifest file

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout"
```

Hope this can be useful.

Answer (score 1):

When you rotate the screen the activity is destroyed and regenereated, so you should check if the activity looks for some parameters (maybe passed using intents and so on) and when it is generated again they aren't present.

Comment: Im setting the intent.class to TransactionConfirmation but why is it starting by its own on rotate action?

Answer (score 0):

issue solved, the problem was I was setting the class for my intent in onCreate() its working fine now after i removed it from there.

thanks for your attention.

regards,